# What is the difference between *s and s[i] in this function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am reading "The C Programming Language" (Kernighan & Ritchie) and in the chapter on pointers, it provides two copies of the 'strcpy' function. One is for arrays and the other is for pointers. I believe the two versions are shown to illustrate a difference between arrays and pointers, but I can't see what.

The array version is:

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
    int i = 0;
    while ((s[i] = t[i]) != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
}
```

The pointer version is:

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
    while ((*s = *t) != '\0') {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}
```

However the book also states '... in evaluating a[i], C converts it to *(a+i) immediately'. In which case surely these two functions are doing the exact same thing?

N.B I am aware that there are more elegant ways of writing this code, I have just copied it exactly as is from the book.

Comment: I'd say, the functions rather illustrate the equivalence of arrays and pointers, as they solve the same problem.

Comment: "the two versions are shown to illustrate a difference between arrays and pointers" - not really. They're just to show you how you can do it with array syntax, and with plain pointer syntax.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are not equivalent though. "array-pointer equivalence" is a misnomer that catches a lot of people out , and it's all just based on one piece of syntactic sugar (or should that be syntactic anthrax) that `s` gets you an rvalue with value equivalent to `&s[0]`, in an rvalue context.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It also works in lvalue contexts, `*s = X` is equivalent to `s[0] = X` even for arrays `s`.

Comment: being the operand of `*` is requesting an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `s`, that's what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe the two versions are shown to illustrate a difference between arrays and pointers.

No, not really. The two versions are used to demonstrate that array indexing can be achieved using either the `a[i]` syntax, or by direct pointer arithmetic.

As you correctly point out, the two versions perform the exact same actions. After all, they are both implementations of `strcpy`. The point is just that the authors are trying to demonstrate different ways to achieve the same end result.

Answer (score 3):

> In which case surely these two functions are doing the exact same thing?

Exactly.

The one version keeps the pointers as they are and adds on each access an offset `i`, which keeps on increasing.

The other version modifies the pointer variables so that directly point to where I want.

Answer (score 0):

`*s` is alternative syntax for `s[0]`.  Look at this version:

```
void my_strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((s[i] = t[i]) != '\0')
    {
        if ( rand() % 2 )
             ++i;
        else
             ++s, ++t;
    }
}
```

This is meant to illustrate that the difference between the two examples is that one increments the index and one increments the base; but those two both achieve the same thing. Whether the `a[b]` or `*(a+b)` form of syntax is used makes no difference, these are identical by definition. It may also help to consider that `s[i]` and `*(s+i)` are alternative syntax for the same thing. Incrementing `s` has the same effect as incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 0):

In the array version , to access array you are using s[i] and by incrementing the index i you can access characters in string.
Where as in case of pointer method you are not using index variable and by incrementing pointer i.e s and t , you are accessing characters in string.That is the diference made in the above programs.Here
*s means *(s+0) equivalent to s[0] and 
s[i] means *(s+i) internally.